# DropDownList change the values in the same times

Tags: development, asp.net

I have got two DropDownLists, and I want to change if I change in first Drop down list Values then I want to change in secound DropdownList. My first DropDownList has got a code:

```
 SPUserCollection userzyWszyscy2 = witryna.SiteUsers;

        // Listowanie userów alfabetyczne

        var listUsers = from SPUser u in userzyWszyscy2
                        orderby u.LoginName
                        select new ListItem(u.LoginName.ToLower());

        DropDownList1.Items.AddRange(listUsers.ToArray());
```

And secound:

```
  SPUserCollection userzyWszyscy2 = witryna.SiteUsers;

                // Listowanie userów alfabetyczne

                var listUsers2 = from SPUser u in userzyWszyscy
                                 orderby u.LoginName
                                 select new ListItem(u.LoginName.ToLower());

                DropDownList3.Items.AddRange(listUsers2.ToArray());
```

How Could I corelate them toogether?

If I change in One I will change in Two.

Comment: Can you please explain what you're trying to do a little better? Are you trying to add the same values to both? or is it more if the first dropdown list changes, you want to reflect the available items on the other?

Comment: Yes I want to add the some Values to both and when first dropdown will change, the secaund DropDownListwill change too.